# Telegram Bot Find Video file_id via Node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Hellow, I'm Using [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) module

How Can I Find out or Console log, Video file_id of other bots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean for your own bot.

If someone forwards a video you can output to console the `file_id` like this:

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (typeof msg.video == 'object') {
        console.log(msg.video.file_id)
    }
})
```

It will ignore all other media/text apart from videos.